# Are role OIDs immutable?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres and trying to figure out the best was to accomplish what I want.

I am aware that OIDs in general are a thing of the past but they they are still used internally by postgres for system tables.

I know that for some things at least, OIDs are not guarantied to to remain the same across a dump and restore, but does that apply to system tables?

More specifically the question is if can I depend on Role OIDs never changing.

I need an unbreakable link between my user table and the user login and have that handled in postgres rather than in the client. As Role names can be changed, it occurred to me that the user (role) OID would be perfect - if it never changes.

So can I count on that?

I looked at the current postgres documentation and that page does not say anything about the persistence of OIDs (very old versions do - but things may have changed and they were taking about things like DB rows not system tables)

Relevant question are are from about 10 years ago and not directly on point for the system tables.

Comment: I can only advise you to not use oid’s. Never. They will be different on a different system or a different moment in time. And you never need them anyway

Comment: 'initdb` will create the basic information for some of the system tables in a new cluster  with predefined oid's for things like system types. Though even [pg_upgrade](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) will not cover certain system oid types: *pg_upgrade does not support upgrading of databases containing table columns using these reg* OID-referencing system data types ...*. For user defined objects the oid is going to be determined by when an object was created and that will almost certainly be different any time you do a dump/restore.  So no you can't count on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object ID of a role is not preserved across a `pg_dumpall` and restore.

You cannot create foreign keys pointing to catalog tables, and that wouldn't be a good idea. The best thing is perhaps to create a trigger that verifies the existence of the user whenever a row in your table is inserted or updated. But you should use the user name rather than the object ID as your reference. Yes, that won't guarantee consistency if you drop or rename roles, but it is the best you can get.

Comment: Thank you... Not the answer I wanted to hear but now i know what to expect.